# Rails: Current user should only be able to view their own users#show page (Devise)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to allow a user to only view their own profile page (users#show)? So when someone with an id of say ***1*** tries to go to the www.myapp.com/users/***412*** url, he will be re-directed to the root page? He can only access www.myapp.com/users/***1***.

I am using devise and this is what I've tried. However with this code strangely enough, the current user cannot access his own page.

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :only_see_own_page, only: [:show]

  def show
    #some ruby code here
  end

  private

  def only_see_own_page
    if current_user.id != params[:id]
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Sorry, but you are only allowed to view your own profile page."
    end
  end
 end
```

**routes.rb*

```
resources :users, only: [:show]
```

Answer (score 2):

Argh, it was that easy... This is what worked for me:

```
def only_see_own_page
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if current_user != @user
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Sorry, but you are only allowed to view your own profile page."
  end
end
```

Comment: You should really consider using an library to manage Authorization. There is a great intro at http://railsapps.github.io/rails-authorization.html.